# Change backarrow position of UINavigationBar backbutton

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to adjust the position of the backbutton arrow in a custom UINavigationBar subclass. This is needed as the position is wrong in a navigationbar with a custom adjusted height.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally fixed it as followed, using imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:

```
 self.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back_detail")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal).imageWithAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -3, 0))
 self.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back_detail")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal).imageWithAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -3, 0))
```

**Edit**

Added some more explanation to clarify the implementation:

```
class VDLNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        // Back button
        self.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back_detail")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal).imageWithAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -3, 0))
        self.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back_detail")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal).imageWithAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -3, 0))    
    }
}
```

Use this custom subclass in your UINavigationController

Comment: What is `backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage`, how did you assign it to backbutton.

Comment: Checkout the edit I just made, you need to create a subclass of the UINavigationBar

Comment: Thank you for this, this also works using UIAppearance, however it seems like the top inset value has no effect on the position of the image but the bottom inset does. I've been playing with this one for hours and never thought to set a bottom inset value until I saw your answer!

Comment: Good to hear. Yes, it's not always the most common way to solve our awesome pixelating problems! :)

Answer (score -2):

you can also try to set UINavigationBar's hidden property to  "True"
and make a UIView instead of using UINavigationbar.

It's also good when you want to customize UITabBarController's TabBar.

Comment: Off course that will do the trick, but this is not the answer needed for this question as he uses the UINavigationBar already.

Comment: I just start to use stack overflow . So I shouldn't provide some other idea to solve the problem since you have answered it? I used to find answers from stack overflow  but this is the first time I know there should only be one answer after you down vote it.

Comment: Welcome to SO at first! No thats actually good, not every answer fits for everybody. Only make sure your answer fits the question.

Comment: Okay~~I'll remember that~